# Can not invoke action after connect react-redux and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

After connecting a component to redux store, i couldn't invoke the action in the container

My container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class CommentBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { comment: '' };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ comment: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.actions.saveComment(this.state.comment);
        this.setState({ comment: '' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                className="comment-box">
                <textarea
                    value={this.state.comment}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                <button action="submit">Submit Comment</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const Container = connect(null, actions)(CommentBox);

export default Container;
```

My action creators

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CommentBox from './comment_box';
import CommentList from './comment_list';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <CommentBox />
          <CommentList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm sure that i have correct imported paths.
When i tried to execute handleSubmit(), the console said

> Can not read property 'saveComment' of undefined

So i had inspected the props in handleSubmit, it was an Object like:

```
default: function () ...
```

There's any actions that i need to be mapped. How can i solve it ? Thank you

Editted:
Here's my actions

```
import SAVE_COMMENT from './types';

export default function saveComment(comment) {
    return {
        type: SAVE_COMMENT,
        payload: comment
    };
};
```

I 've also found that i exported action creator as default. So that when i imported it with `import * as action` , i had an object that looked like

```
{ default: function saveComment() }
```

It made mapDispatchToProps mapping default property to container's props. To fix it i simply delete `default` when export saveComment and it worked perfectly. Thank you everyone

Comment: Can you show us your actions?

Answer (score 2):

That is not the right way to use actions in your component. You have to make sure that the actions are wrapped in a dispatch method. In your case, I would create another function mapDispatchToProps and Use [bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html). See my code below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class CommentBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { comment: '' };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ comment: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.props.actions.saveComment(this.state.comment);
        this.setState({ comment: '' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                className="comment-box">
                <textarea
                    value={this.state.comment}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                <button action="submit">Submit Comment</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

// use bindActionCreators here
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
})

const Container = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CommentBox);

export default Container;
```

Comment: i 've tried but nothing changed. still the existing problem

Comment: it's my mistake when i exported saveComment action creator as default. However, the way i pass actions directly to connect() helper 's still worked.

Comment: @mhdev really? can you actually confirm that the reducer is getting your actions?

Comment: @D-reaper surely, i found it in react-redux api doc

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: @mhdev Yes, specifically here it is: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-and-all-action-creators-addtodo-completetodo--as-actions. So there is no way what you are doing is correct because you have to wrap your action creators in a dispatch.

Comment: @D-reaper yes, i mean i passed actions as an argument of connect() helper as the api doc show.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-and-all-action-creators
and because the actions i had imported is all functions from actions.js so there's no need to specify an particular object with bindActionCreators. i think redux-react 'll do it for us

Comment: Ah I see, my mistake. I didn't know that you can just pass in the action creators like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're importing actions, as done here `import * as actions from '../actions';`, you should be able to access your action by doing `actions.saveComment(this.state.comment);` in `handleSubmit()`

Comment: This is incorrect. `connect` does not take actions as an argument. It takes `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, either can be a null value. If both are a null value it makes `dispatch` available as a prop in the connected component., and does not connect the component to the store.